# Angular Select Object Index

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have following object:

[Json Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YkUe.png)

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="element.version"
            (selectionChange)="onVersionChange(element)">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let versionObj of versionDatasetMap[element.datasetName];"
               [value]="versionObj.version">
    {{versionObj.version}}
  </mat-option>
<mat-select>
```

TS Code:

```
onVersionChange(element) {
 console.log(element);  
}
```

Always returns Array Object 0.  Even if select version 1 or 2. I'm trying to manipulate the element Object index i'm selecting from the json object. Much appreciated.

Comment: Why would changing version drop down trigger your for loop to refresh, the for loop seems to refresh at page load only..

Comment: it's not refreshing it's always returning the array[0] object.  I can't seem to get the the array[1] object or array[2] object.

Comment: That’s right it’s always returning the default regardless of drop down, because it’s not listening to onVersionChange event, may be you need to add to that..

Answer (score 0):

Element is a local variable in the component, you should not pass `element` as an argument from the UI into this method as it will be a copy and not the original... just interact with the component version directly.

```
onVersionChange() {
 console.log(this.element);  
}
```

Comment: but i need to manipulate the object based on the selected version.  Like the changing the description of the object that i selected based on version.  I get undefined.

Comment: Because you are using [(ngModel)]="element.version" the version is already changing on selection, look at console.log(this.element) and you will see the version changing. If you need help beyond this create a stackblitz and either myself or someone else will help.